# Replace table info with new one and make table look the same?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this code that has a table with all the products the user has clicked to buy. When page loaded I want to replace the info I have in the column with info from local storage but I'm not able to do it and I don't know why...

Html:

```
<div class="rTable">
  <div class="rTitleRow">
    <div class="rTableHead"><strong>Producto</strong></div>
    <div class="rTableHead"><span style="font-weight: bold;">Preço</span></div>
    <div class="rTableHead">Quantidade</div>
  </div>
  <div class="rTableRow">
    <div class="rTableCell">T-shirt World</div>
    <div class="rTableCell">
      <p class="cart-price">14.99€</p>
    </div>
    <div class="rTableCell"><input style="width:50px;height: 20px;" type="number" class="quantity" name="quantity" min="1">
      <button class="btn-danger">Remover</button></div>
  </div>
  <div class="rTableRow">
    <div class="rTableCell">T-shirt World</div>
    <div class="rTableCell">
      <p class="cart-price">14.99€</p>
    </div>
    <div class="rTableCell"><input style="width:50px;height: 20px;" type="number" class="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" value="1"> <button class="btn-danger">Remover</button></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function reloadShoppingCart() {
  var storedInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("names"));
  var cartRow = document.createElement('div');
  cartRow.classList.add('rTableRow')
  var classy = "rTableCell"
  var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('rTable')[0]
  var item_name =
    var size = storedInfo[0]
  var cartRows = '<div class="rTableRow"> <div class="rTableCell">${item_name}</div> <div class="rTableCell"><p class="cart-price">14.99€</p></div> <div class="rTableCell"><input style="width:50px;height: 20px;" type="number" class="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" value="1">               <button class="btn-danger" >Remover</button></div> </div>'
  cartRow.innerHTML = cartRows
  cartItems.append(cartRow)
}
```

Comment: When do you call that reloadShoppingCart function?

Comment: Hey, you're writing javascript, why there're `${item_name}` in variable `cartRows`

Comment: @JackTing that is part of [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), however OP is using regular strings so it will not render the value in the string.

Comment: You double the `<div class="rTableRow">`. `cartRow` is `<div class="rTableRow">` itself, and its `innerHTML` also contains `<div class="rTableRow">`.